# Creative solution for draggable images wrapped in anchor tags?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using Chris Coyier's "Draggable" script which makes elements draggable (without jquery UI):

```
(function($) {
$.fn.drags = function(opt) {

    opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:"pointer"}, opt);

    if(opt.handle === "") {
        var $el = this;
    } else {
        var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
    }

    return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
        } else {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
        }
        var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
            drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
            drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
            pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
            pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
        $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
            $('.draggable').offset({
                top:e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
            }).on("mouseup", function() {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
            });
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // disable selection
    }).on("mouseup", function() {
        if(opt.handle === "") {
            $(this).removeClass('draggable');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
        }
    });

  }

})(jQuery);
```

The way it gets initialized is:

```
$('#containerness img').drags();
```

The problem is that those images, which are now draggable, are wrapped in anchor tags which are bound to my jquery lightbox script (I won't post the lightbox script here because it's minified and pretty big).

Therefore, if you click and drag the image, the same click event opens the lightbox, too.

Is there a way to preclude the lightbox from firing off IF the image is getting dragged, but keep the lightbox if no dragging occurs? Or something like, "IF dragging happens, ignore the A HREF" that the image is wrapped in?

I've been looking at this code for way too long. I even tried binding the lightbox to double-click instead of click, but realized halfway through that no one double-clicks anymore so it's probably best not to go there. :)

Comment: The code is a mess, and I'm pretty sure it has memory leaks. It looks like it adds a new `mousemove` and `mouseup`event EVERY time you trigger the `mousedown` event. I would find new code.

Comment: When you say "click and drag", do you actually mean "mousedown and drag"? Also, are you referring to **[this](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)** Lightbox?

Comment: There's a million lightbox scripts in the world, and you're trying to guess which one I'm using?